# Can we detect if resize event is triggered by zooming on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I was using a function triggered by `resize` to dynamically adjust the layout of my page, which I use to make sure my page looks good when users expand/reduce their address bars on mobile. But now I found that sometimes `resize` would also be triggered when user zoom in or out using two fingers or double taps, in which case I don't want the function related to `resize` event to be triggered.

Is there a way to detect whether the `resize` event is triggered by zooming?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can disable zoom pinching functionality on mobile devices with the scale meta tag like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

But, if you still want your users to be able to pinch zoom then you can observe the "devicePixelRatio" value for changes. This value actually refer to the device scale:

```
window.devicePixelRatio
```

[Here is a link to Mozilla documentation about this.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio#monitoring_screen_resolution_or_zoom_level_changes)